# Issue partitioning with paragon partition manager

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning, paragon

I have 4 primary partitions, one of them is windows partition and one is a 100MB system reserved and I want to convert my other primaries to logicals and place them into one extended partition so I will be able to create two more primaries to install my Fedora19 ( an 8GB one for swap and a 30GB one for Fedora) but there is no option to convert one of those partitions to extended I can only convert them to logical.

1. So, is it necessary to create an extended partition, can't I just create two logicals?
2. If so how can I create an extended and then create two logicals inside it?
3. I'm using paragon partition manager 12 but I can use other software if you recommend it.

Comment: You have to delete one of the 4 primary partitions to create an extended partition which can have more logical partitions inside it. Either that, or back up the data, change the disk from MBR to GPT, then create as many "primary" partitions as you want merrily.

Comment: two things can't i just create two logicals without extended

Comment: if i can't can i convert one of my partitions to logical and then create an extended and put that logical inside it then create the second logical?

Comment: They are logical because they are inside the extended, otherwise they might as well be primary. As for doing all that you said above, I've never attempted something so complex. IMO it's best to start afresh if possible, otherwise see if GParted can help you do all this. In any case ensure all your data is backed up.